# How to push new index and value to php array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching data from a table using group by payment method. What happen is in group by the data comes up corresponding to those data only which are in table . But I want all payment types to be shown in result .
I am using following query.

```
 $query = "select  paytype ,sum(totalamount)  from `tbl_payments` group by paytype";
```

There are 5(cash,credit,paypal..) types of payment . I want all the payment methods with the result , so that if paytype is not find by query result it should be appended like `['credit'] =>[0]` , means `paytype => amount(which should be 0 at that case)`.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please show us full code.

Comment: A schema may help aswell

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell about the table `paytype` containing the list of valid payment methods.

To get all the payment methods in the result, you must use a left join. Something like :

```
select pt.paytype, sum(p.totalamount)
from `tbl_paytypes` pt
left join `tbl_payments` p 
on pt.paytype = p.paytype 
group by pt.paytype
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all payment types using a Left Join with the paymettypes tables

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use entity class,
ex.

```
class PaymentTypes{  private $cash;  private $credit;  private $paypal;  ....

//constructor

//setters and getters }
```

in constructor you can set a default parameters for the fields if you dont get any values

```
public function __construct($array){   $someDefaultValue = '';   if(!empty($array['name_of_column_in_databaseTable'])){   $this->$cash
= $array['name_of_column_in_databaseTable'];  }else{   $this->$cash = $someDefaultValue; } ... }
```

Result from database is like array(array(), array(), ...)

so you can make:

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
 $paymentTypes[] = new PaymentTypes($value);
}
```